# Convert shortened month name to its longer counterpart

Tags: java

I need to convert shortened versions of month names to its longer representation (e.g "Dec" -> "December"). The months name is a String and I would rather not convert it to a date object first.

Is there an easy way to do this?

Edit:
My problem was associated with inserting "Dec" as a table name in mysql (which of-course throws a syntax error) and for my use case it would be nicer to change this value earlier than to let mysql commands change it.

Comment: the easy way is to convert to date object first. Or else, `if-else` or `switch` is your options

Comment: There is no easy way to do this.  You'll first need to write a compiler.

Comment: If you don't want to convert it to a Date Object, then I would just     if-else 
it.

Comment: My initial implementation used a hashmap with the key-value pairs, although I suppose as you suggested @RafaEl switch statements would be better

Comment: @JasonC Not really.  Solutions would be rather trivial; no fun at all. Oh! code trolling might be still ok.

Comment: @JasonC I realized that you mentioned code-trolling after posting the initial comment.  It'd be good to see answers with a bit of obfuscation.

Comment: @JasonC An even better one was to add two integers.  I recall one of the answers posting a _snippet_!

Comment: @devnull http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/25207/convert-short-month-names-to-their-longer-counterparts

Comment: @JasonC haha, I'll be voting!

Comment: @JasonC Complex problem.  Trying to find an optimal solution `:)`

Comment: If you were willing to use a date-time library such as Joda-Time or java.time, the solution could be generalized to handle internationalization of month names in various languages.

Comment: @devnull I was only looking for advice on a simple problem, at-least you had fun bashing the question

Comment: @eddie The comment you're probably referring to wasn't directed at this question.  It was meant for the codegolf question link shared by JasonC.  Apologies if you felt hurt.  (In fact much of the comments around are related to codegolf.)

Comment: @eddie Ha, sorry! Your question here is actually very good. I just also thought it would double as a funny topic for PCG. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious way is:

```
if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("Jan"))
    month = "January";
else if (month.equalsIgnoreCase("Feb"))
    month = "February";
// and so on...
```

That could also be represented with a `switch`, if you prefer:

```
switch (month.toLowerCase()) {
case "jan": month = "January"; break;
case "feb": month = "February"; break;
// and so on...
}
```

Or, a more forgiving version:

```
if (month.toLowerCase().startsWith("Jan"))
    month = "January";
// and so on...
```

I suppose you could store them in a map first:

```
Map<String,String> monthNames = new HashMap<String,String>();
monthNames.put("jan", "January");
monthNames.put("feb", "February");
// and so on...

String shortMonth = "Jan";
String month = monthNames.get(shortMonth.toLowerCase());
if (month == null)
    month = shortMonth;
```

Using a map lets you easily add translations to other languages, I suppose. You could also automatically use the current locale with [Russell Zahniser's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22800803/616460) nice answer.

There doesn't seem to be much reason to parse them into dates and back (although if you do, see [newuser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22800745/616460)).

There's a lot of ways to do this.

Comment: Initially I was using the HashMap solution, although the switch statement solution will work best for my use case. Thanks!

Comment: `if (month.toLowerCase().startsWith("Jan"))` Pretty sure that's a typo.

Answer (score 3):

Try this, Use this format to get the full value **MMMM**

```
       String month = "Dec";
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        try
        {
            Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(month);
            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
            System.out.println(simpleDateFormat.format(date));
        }
        catch (ParseException ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Exception "+ex);
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

To do this using the month names configured for the user's locale:

```
// Set up a lookup table like this:

Map<String,String> shortToLong = new HashMap<String,String>();
DateFormatSymbols symbols = new DateFormatSymbols();

for(int i = 0; i < symbols.getMonths().length; i++) {
   shortToLong.put(symbols.getShortMonths()[i], symbols.getMonths()[i]);
}

// Then use like this:

String longMonth = shortToLong.get(shortMonth);
```

Comment: +1 This is nice because it obeys the current locale. Maybe toss some `toLowerCase()`'s in there if case doesn't matter for the short names.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way of doing this is to start with the long month names, then abbreviate each one and see which one matches the given input.

```
String s="MAR";
String months[]={"January","February","March","April","May","June","July","August","September","October","November","December"};
for(String i : months) {
    if(i.substring(0,3).equalsIgnoreCase(s)) {
        System.out.println(i);
        break;
    }
}
```